# Sony CDs and "Rootkit scandal"

Tags: music, rootkit

I recently bought a secondhand copy of a CD that was part of the Sony "Rootkit Scandal" in 2005. I assume it to be infected until proven otherwise. Am I safe to try to rip this on my PC with modern AV software to protect me?

Comment: Sweet, a vintage rootkit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This software is installed automatically only when AutoRun is enabled. This was a security issue anyway and thus disabled on Windows XP, IIRC. In recent versions of Windows, you have to explicitly confirm that you want to run the AutoRun program, in the AutoPlay dialog. Please note that double-clicking on the drive in Explorer might also launch the program.

According to [this guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Protect-Yourself-from-Sony-DRM-Rootkit-Malware), you also have to accept an EULA before the DRM rootkit is installed.

So it’s rather unlikely this would still work today—unless you actively ignore all safety measures, of course.

Comment: Thank you for that @Daniel B. I thought the Autoplay pop-up would stop it from installing - but the Wiki page seems to suggest otherwise. According to that page, it also installs the rootkit even if you DON'T accept the EULA,

Comment: No, the AutoPlay popup *has* to stop it. While it may be a rootkit, it doesn’t rely on any vulnerabilities to get started. Someone (AutoRun or the user) has to start the program.